# performance or optimization in Android : final local variable vs local variable

Tags: java, android, performance, final

I doubt that final local variables are more optimized by the Java compiler or dex than the local variables without final.
Is there any difference between final variable and variable as to the Android performance?

Thanks.

for-loop:

```
for (final int x : list) ret += x;
```

try-catch:

```
try { /* do something */ } catch (final IOException e) {}
```

function:

```
void echo(final String s) { print(s); }
```

Comment: Try it and find out?

Comment: check this http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#UseFinal

Comment: There's other reasons to use final.  It isn't about performance, its about immutability.

Comment: @immibis yes, but no difference.

Comment: @ISSKJ well, there's your answer.

Comment: I understand about using final static as constants. and I understand using final is best practice but how about the unnecessarily final like above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think there are any performance difference between declare final and local.We declare a variable final when we don't want someone override this variable that is you cannot change the value of final variable(It will be constant).This optimization applies only to primitive types and String constants, not arbitrary reference types. Still, it's good practice to declare constants static final whenever possible.

Answer (score 9):

I actually saw some video from Google Devs and I remember at some point they say that when you declaring your variable `final` VM understands that this variable wouldn't change it it improves performance.
I would add links as I find that. So maybe the accepted answer is not true.

Comment: On a related note: Apple's `Swift` gives an error whenever you DON'T declare a variable as a constant, that is never modified. They heavily encourage declaring variables as constants, for performance reasons they claim.